# mvc 4 mobile display changing image banner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

Is it possible to display a changing image banner in MVC4 mobile? if so, does anybody have an example? I am new to this and I am clueless on how to approach this

Comment: Yes i did! I used the Jquery Cycle Plugin:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
extremely easy to use, also developed my own Jquery Slider but it was a bit more complicated, i would recommend to use the plugin for better results.